# Where can I find documentation for the dsp-tikz library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation, tikzlibrary

I would like to track down the best source of documentation for the (digital signal processing) dsp-tikz library.

An example using the library is shown [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fir-filter/).

Comment: Doesn't look like there is any documentation accompanying that library (nothing in the `tds.zip` file), so the code may be the best documentation.

Comment: It would be useful to have a very basic legend table where all of the symbols and corresponding names are displayed.  I find the following symbol names in the code: `dspadder`, `dspmultiplier`, `dspmixer`, `dspnodeopen`, `dspnodefull`, `dspsquare`, `dspfilter`, `dspline`, `dspconn`, `dspflow`

Comment: Why don't you make one?